# Compress and archive files in a directory which starting with a spesific letter

Tags: bash, unix, tar

I would like to compress and archive all files starting with "a" letter in /bin directory.
I can compress and archive all files with

```
tar -zcvf ~/Desktop/archive.tar.gz /usr/bin
```

This code compress the files and then sends the file to the desktop but what should I add to code in order to compress files starting with a spesific letter?

Comment: Use the letter and an asterisk like this: `tar -zcvf ~/Desktop/archive.tar.gz /usr/bin/a*`

Comment: @masterguru But this will also archive _directories_ beginning with `a`.

Comment: @M. Nejat Aydin: I know, I saw that in the anwser of Cyrus, he is right, but my first comment was already set and not able to edit it again. Should I delete it?  Berkay doruk: Try Cyrus answer too, it is better than mine in order to store only files. And if you are happy with it mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
tar -zcvf ~/Desktop/archive.tar.gz `find . -maxdepth 1  -type f -name 'a*' -print`
```

It might require GNU `find`.